# How to check 2 list and rearrange the order in python

Tags: python

I have a parent list `['Python', 'Java', 'c#', 'Csharp']`

if my input list `['c#', 'Java']`

From the input list I need to arrange the order as in parent list

Expected out is `['Java', 'c#']`

If the input list is empty `[]` then output list `['Python']`

1 more scenario for testing

input >> `['Python', 'Java', 'Csharp', 'c#']` Output >> `['Python', 'Java', 'c#', 'Csharp']`

DO i need to create a order dictionary and compare like below?

- `{'Python':1, 'Java':2, 'c#':3, 'Csharp':4}`
- Then check the input and sort it or any other way?

Comment: You can iterate through the parent list and if each element in the parent list is present in the input list, print parent list element else ignore. That will give you the correct order

Comment: Do you want to return `c#` if the value is sent in lowercase? Similarly, if value is `java` or `JAVA` or `JAva`, do you want it to consider all the scenarios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the Parent list and check if each element in the parent list is also in the input_list. If they are, then you should print the element in the parent list.

You also want to check if input_list is empty. If empty, you want to print Python. So add that condition as well.

Here's the code to get this done. Its a list comprehension to get the output list.

```
parent_list = ['Python', 'Java', 'c#', 'Csharp']

def get_output(input_list):
    if input_list:
        return [x for x in parent_list if x in input_list]
    else:
        return ['Python']

print (get_output(['c#', 'Java']))

print (get_output([]))

print (get_output(['Python', 'Java', 'Csharp', 'c#']))
```

The output for this will be:

```
['Java', 'c#']
['Python']
['Python', 'Java', 'c#', 'Csharp']
```

Comment: its is c# not C#, c is small letter

Comment: Updated code to reflect lowercase c in c#

Answer (score 1):

You simply iterate through parent list to see if item is in the input list and append it.  You also add the special condition about the empty input list as follows:

```
output = []
if not input:
    output.append('Python')
for item in parent:
    if item in input:
        output.append(item)
print(output)
```

Comment: You code will only output  ['Java'] if input is  ['c#', 'Java']

Comment: That's because in your parent list you have upper case C and in the input you have lower case c.

Comment: Yeah I see, the example given have got it mixed up

Comment: my c is small letter

Comment: try not to use input as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` along with `zip`

`key=lambda pair: pair[0]` will sort the values in output list based on order in Y (parent_list)

```
def func(X, Y):
    op_list = [x for y, x in sorted(zip(Y,X), key=lambda pair: pair[0]) if x in Y]
    if not X:
        op_list = ['Python']

    return op_list

print(func(input_list, parent_list))
```

Comment: can you explain it key=lambda pair: pair[0], can you write in multiple lines instead of list comprehension

Comment: I tried with `parent_list = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green']` 
`input_list = ["Yellow", "Green"]` i got wrong output

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer you're looking for. Hope this may be of help

```
for item in parent_list:
    if item in input_list:
        output_list.append(item)
    elif not bool(input_list):
        output_list = 'Python'
```

Comment: this is because c# is in lower case instead of upper like the parent list